# JourneyBuilder Custom Activity Notify Payload - DataExtension record Information?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I have an Installed Package with a Journey Builder Activity.

Upon notify of a Contact entering this Activity in a Journey, I am able to receive Contact.Id, Contact.Key, and Contact.Default.Email as part of the payload to my application.

I am looking for other information, specifically information about which row in the DataExtension configured with the Journey the Contact belongs.

I can currently relate the Contact.Key to Subscriber.Key, then use Subscriber.Key to retrieve a subset of DataExtension records, but is there a way to configure the notify payload to simply give me the record Id or some other piece of information that easily allows me to retrieve the correct DE record?

What other information can I configure the Activity to send me upon Notify?  I have had some trouble finding a comprehensive help doc on the subject.